# Read and Update File Properties

Tags: qt, qml, metadata, qtquick2, qtmultimedia

I'm using `FolderListModel` to display lists with file names, but I can't figure out how to read additional file properties.

My primary concern is to read the media fields such as album, genre, length, etc. I'd also like to be able to save those to fields if possible. Ideally this would be platform independent, but if that is not possible then Windows is most important followed by Linux and Android.

I have been unable to find any information on this. I'm currently using Qt 5.3.2, but I could upgrade, if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The properties you ask for are not part of the file system, they are file specific properties, usually stored as meta data, and as such, they are not covered by the file system model.

You should use [QtMultimedia](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediametadata.html) or look at 3rd party solution like [taglib](https://taglib.github.io/) instead.

Last but not least, the QML [`Audio`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-audio.html) and [`MediaPlayer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html) elements support reading metadata out of the box. So you can use an `Audio` element to load each file, extract the needed metadata, and populate a model for each media file. I am not sure how efficient will that be thou...

Comment: Qt Multimedia module can provide the metadata too ( [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediametadata.html) ), no need to go outside Qt Framework.

Comment: Is there a QML module I can use?

Comment: I decided to write it in C++ and then pass the information to the QML app using signals and slots, but it looks to me that to get the metadata with Qt Multimedia I would need to load each file in the player (which is not a viable solution for a list). Taglib looks like a great solution, and from a post on how to compile it [can be built inside Qt Creator](http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-compile-taglib-on-windows/).